# Permission denied with MinGW even as administrator

Tags: c, windows, mingw, permission-denied

I recently updated my MinGW installation on Windows 10, so I tried to compile a quick sample program in C. No problem, it compiles.

However, when I try to compile after the first time, I get an error telling me that MinGW can't access the exe file. I tried to run MinGW as administrator, without success.

Then, I tried to delete the exe. And I found that, even as administrator, and even with the hidden administrator account, I can't delete it. "Permission denied" and so on. I can't edit file's permissions neither.

So the question is simple: what's going on?

Comment: the exe is probably running in the background. Kill it / reboot your computer you'll be fine.

Comment: I already looked in taskmgr... and there's nothing. I'll try to reboot.

Comment: Well. I just rebooted. And the exe simply disappeared. The question is now: why did it disappear? Is it because I tried to delete it and Windows deleted it on shutdown?

Comment: Did you download your MinGW from sourceforge? https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/

Comment: If facing access-right issues, I'd recommend to 1st  inspect .. well - access rights to the files in question, right? This, BTW, might include inspecting the files' ownership.

Comment: I downloaded the version shipped with the latest version of CodeBlocks.

Comment: Concerning the ownership, I can't even access the name of the owner. It seems - because I've the same issue with Cygwin - that the owner is "Unknown User". I also found I had to press a key in CodeBlocks' console instead of directly closing the window to avoid the issue.

Comment: If a **f**ile is opened as a kernel **F**ile object with delete sharing, then it can be opened again as another File that has delete access. All File instances of a file reference a common file or stream control block (FCB/SCB) in the filesystem. The File with delete access can be used to set the delete disposition on the FCB. Note that this is a disposition that can be set and reset. Windows filesystems don't immediately unlink a 'deleted' file. The filesystem does that when the last File object reference to the file is destroyed -- typically when all user-mode handles have been closed.

Comment: No new File objects can be created for an FCB that's in the deleted state. So attempts to open it again with delete access will fail with access denied. Only existing handles for File references that have delete access can be used to set and unset the delete disposition. However the file remains visibly linked in its parent directory -- basically in a zombie state -- until all handles to it are closed. Once it's no longer referenced by any kernel File objects, the filesystem will unlink the file if its delete disposition is set.

Comment: Thank you for these details.

Comment: @Sisyphe Can you mark my answer as correct solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is a file problem and has nothing to do with MinGW. Look into Windows file ownership and rights

Answer (score 0):

In a current window try a command bellow ...to add your current folder executable.
Then it temporarily works at least at my side.

```
export PATH=${PATH}:.
```